# Connecting to different networks to access database information

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, ax

Any suggestions would help. The issue is, I have ETL applications that need to access database information located on a different network. So one C# application needs to query a database located on a different server.  Now I know the options are to open up a tcp port on the host and open up the firewall but I don't think we will go for that.  Other option I was thinking was to create a web service WCF and pass query string to the service and then connect to the database and return the info.

Another application needs to access dynamics AX to a AIF web service. Can aif web services be accessed across different networks or would I have to use a web service or something and then connect to the AIF service to retrieve information.

Comment: For both applications, I think your best bet is to create a service to provide both data sets. This will create a decoupling layer (in case you change databases or remove the AIF service).

Comment: How about about using an AWS Sql Instance as an intermediary

Answer (score 0):

> Another application needs to access dynamics AX to a AIF web service.
>   Can aif web services be accessed across different networks or would I
>   have to use a web service or something and then connect to the AIF
>   service to retrieve information.

IF you need to access AIF only in Intranet, you can do that with normal AIF services (They use RCP, I think but cannot assure just now).

If you need to access AIF via extranets or Internet, the best option is usually to create and Advanced AIF Port of HTTP type. This will create a standard Web Service, with SOAP protocol and a proper WSDL available for it. Be careful in securing these webservices properly, specially in production environments.